# Merging uploaded images from mysql table into single pdf file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, itext, mysql-workbench

I have uploaded documents (only image format) to mysql database through c#.  This entry in the database table will have reference Id for each transaction.   Upon clicking on download button, all uploaded images of respective table id should merge into a single pdf file.  How can I Achieve this?.  Require C# code to download

Below is the sample code which is not working.  It returns system.byte[] as response

```
    [HttpPost]
    public static byte[] MergeFile()
    {

        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

        using (iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
        {
            doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
                using (PdfCopy pdf = new `enter code here`PdfCopy(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext(connection, false))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var getDocs = context.Document.Where(p => p.ReferenceId == 1).ToList();
                                foreach (DAL.Document info in getDocs)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        doc.NewPage();
                                        iTextSharp.text.Document imageDocument = null;
                                        PdfWriter imageDocumentWriter = null;
                                        switch (info.Extension.Trim('.').ToLower())
                                        {

                                            case "image/png":
                                                using (imageDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
                                                {
                                                    using (var imageMS = new MemoryStream())
                                                    {
                                                        using (imageDocumentWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(imageDocument, imageMS))
                                                        {
                                                            imageDocument.Open();
                                                            if (imageDocument.NewPage())
                                                            {
                                                                var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(info.Documents);
                                                                image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                                                                image.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize.Width - 10, doc.PageSize.Height - 10);
                                                                if (!imageDocument.Add(image))
                                                                {
                                                                    throw new Exception("Unable to add image to page!");
                                                                }
                                                                imageDocument.Close();
                                                                imageDocumentWriter.Close();
                                                                using (PdfReader imageDocumentReader = new PdfReader(imageMS.ToArray()))
                                                                {
                                                                    var page = pdf.GetImportedPage(imageDocumentReader, 1);
                                                                    pdf.AddPage(page);
                                                                    imageDocumentReader.Close();
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                break;

                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.Data["FileName"]=info.DocumentName;
                                        throw e;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                var k = e.Message;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
                  if (doc.IsOpen()) doc.Close();
                            return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```